# Conectar java con mysql

Tags: java, mysql

Tengo una simple aplicación de java, que tiene 2 opciones, mostrar la cantidad de latas de pintura en el inventario, y mostrar la suma de los precios de todas las latas de pintura, y tengo todo esos datos en una simple base de datos en MySQL, mi pregunta es como puedo conectar java con MySQL, para cuando ejecute mi programa en Java y seleccione la opción 1, me haga el query correspondiente?

Comment: ¿Que has intentado?

Comment: Recuerda poner el conextor en tu JAVALIB

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Para conectar Java con MySQL es fácil, solo tienes que seguir unos sencillos pasos.

Paso 1.
Necesitas el JDBC driver de MySQL. Puedes descargarlo en el siguiente enlace [aquí](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/). Si estás usando Windows, asegúrate de descargar la versión que está en ZIP.

Paso 2.
Debes agregar el JDBC que es un archivo `.jar` a tu proyecto, es decir, al Build-Path de tu proyecto. Si estás usando Eclipse, puedes agregar el archivo haciendo clic con el botón derecho en el nombre de tu **Proyecto > Build Path > Configure Build Path**. En la pestaña **Libraries**, haces clic en **Add Jars** si el archivo lo copiaste a la carpeta de tu proyecto o en **Add External JARs** si tienes el archivo en otro directorio de tu computadora. Luego, haces clic en el botón inferior que dice Apply and Close.

Paso 3. Debes crear una clase con un nombre distintivo, ejemplo `ConexionMySQL`.

Esta clase se verá de la siguiente manera (he comentado cada línea para que entiendas):

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class ConexionMySQL {

    // Librería de MySQL
    public String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";

    // Nombre de la base de datos
    public String database = "databasemovies";

    // Host
    public String hostname = "localhost";

    // Puerto
    public String port = "3306";

    // Ruta de nuestra base de datos (desactivamos el uso de SSL con "?useSSL=false")
    public String url = "jdbc:mysql://" + hostname + ":" + port + "/" + database + "?useSSL=false";

    // Nombre de usuario
    public String username = "root";

    // Clave de usuario
    public String password = "123456789";

    public Connection conectarMySQL() {
        Connection conn = null;

        try {
            Class.forName(driver);
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return conn;
    }

}
```

Paso 4. Otra clase donde harás INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, etc...

Por ejemplo, tenemos una clase llamada `Insertar`, en ella tendrás lo siguiente:

```
// Instancias la clase que hemos creado anteriormente
private ConexionMySQL SQL = new ConexionMySQL();
// Llamas al método que tiene la clase y te devuelve una conexión
private Connection conn = SQL.conectarMySQL();
// Query que usarás para hacer lo que necesites
private String sSQL =   "";
```

Ejemplo, cómo hago INSERT?. Debes hacer uso de esto:

```
// Query
sSQL =  "INSERT INTO USERS (first_name, last_name) VALUES (?, ?)";
// PreparedStatement
PreparedStatement pstm = conn.prepareStatement(sSQL);
```

Solo te faltaría el resto del código necesario correspondiente al `PreparedStatement` para insertar correctamente los datos a la base de datos, el cual es otro tema que no tiene cabida en tu pregunta.

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Donde encuentro la Build-Path de mi proyecto?

Comment: Qué IDE estás usando? Eclipse?, si es Eclipse, he editado mi respuesta en el Paso 2 con los detalles para hacerlo.

Answer (score 4):

Bien **darioxlz**  debes usar el jdbc que lo puedes descargar desde aquí https://www.mysql.com/products/connector/

una ves que añadas el jdbc.
la conexion es la siguientes:

```
package servicios;
import java.sql.*;

public class Conexion {
private static Connection cnx = null;
public static Connection obtener() throws SQLException,  ClassNotFoundException {
  if (cnx == null) {
     try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        cnx = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/java_mysql", "root", "");
     } catch (SQLException ex) {
        throw new SQLException(ex);
     } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        throw new ClassCastException(ex.getMessage());
     }
  }
  return cnx;
  }

public static void cerrar() throws SQLException {
  if (cnx != null) {
     cnx.close();
  }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

***2 SOLUCIONES QUE FUNCIONAN:***
**Clase principal con método MAIN**

```
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class Principal {
/** Clase principal y método MAIN */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String consulta="SELECT title,length FROM film";
        
        try {
            Statement sentencia=Conexion.obtener().createStatement();
            ResultSet resultado=sentencia.executeQuery(consulta);
            while (resultado.next())
            {
                System.out.println (resultado.getString (1) + " " + resultado.getInt(2));
            }
            
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
            
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

**Clase Conexión**

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class Conexion {
    private static Connection cnx = null;

    public static Connection obtener() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        if (cnx == null) {
            try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                cnx = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sakila", "root", "");
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                throw new SQLException(ex);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                throw new ClassCastException(ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
        return cnx;
    }

    public static void cerrar() throws SQLException {
        if (cnx != null) {
            cnx.close();
        }
    }
}
```

**Otra solución puede ser:**
**Clase principal, método MAIN**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.Connection;

public class Principal {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String servidor;
        String usuario;
        String contrasenya;
        String bd;
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        Connection conexion;
        String consulta;
        
        System.out.println("Bienvenido,introduzca el servidor");
        servidor=sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Introduzca el usuario");
        usuario=sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Introduzca la contraseña");
        contrasenya=sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Para finalizar, introduzca la BD");
        bd=sc.nextLine();
        conexion=ConexionMySQL.getConector(servidor, bd, usuario, contrasenya);
        
        System.out.println("Introduzca su consulta MySQL por favor:");
        consulta=sc.nextLine();
        
        try {
            Statement sentencia=conexion.createStatement();
            ResultSet resultado=sentencia.executeQuery(consulta);
            while (resultado.next())
            {
                System.out.println (resultado.getString (1) + " " + resultado.getInt(2));
            }
            
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        

    }

}
```

**Clase conexion:**

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Connection;

public class ConexionMySQL {
    
    public static Connection getConector(String servidor,String bd,String user,String pswd) {
        Connection conexion = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            String URL="jdbc:mysql://"+servidor+":8889/"+bd;
            conexion=DriverManager.getConnection(URL,user,pswd);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return conexion;
    }

}
```

***GRACIAS POR LAS SOLUCIONES APORTADAS, QUE ME HAN SERVIDO PARA ENTENDER MEJOR COMO FUNCIONA LA CONEXIÓN. UN SALUDO A TODOS.***